# How to make Fragments to be stateful in an Android Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, stateful

I'm a newbie in Android.
I am trying to figure out how to create a stateful fragment based on MVVM with a SavedStateHandle injection.
I have created an empty project in Android Studio based on a template with bottom navigation. Then I added a text input into DashboardFragment. I want the text of this input to be saved when user switches between tabs.
At the moment I get access to VM as follows:

```
private val application = activity?.application

private val viewModel: DashboardViewModel by viewModels {
    SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, activity as SavedStateRegistryOwner)
}
```

And I get an exception

> ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered

Please, help me to find out what is wrong

Source code: https://github.com/ideogram-software/statefulfragments-tests/

Comment: Why are you defining a factory at all? The default factory already does the right thing for storing the state on a per fragment basis.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have already tried the default like this: private val viewModel: DashboardViewModel by viewModels()   but state is not saved anyway.

Comment: You need to add a ``SavedStateHandle`` as a constructor parameter on your view model: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate#setup

Comment: @cactustictacs Yes, but it is already done in https://github.com/ideogram-software/statefulfragments-tests/blob/4f71d735d6a395eb9afcf8c582fc139553db1a3d/app/src/main/java/dev/ideogram/statefulfragments/ui/dashboard/DashboardViewModel.kt#L8
However default state is recreated every time the fragment is activated

Comment: How are you actually setting the value on ``textName``? (I'm assuming that's the one you're talking about.) You need to set it *through* the ``savedStateHandle``, e.g. ``state["textName"] = "Something else"``. That way it's saved in the state, and the ``LiveData`` you created from ``state`` for that key will update with the new value

Comment: @cactustictacs So, I have to add `fun setTextName(name: String) { state["textName"] = name }` into my View Model and call it in the fragment `override fun onDestroyView() {  viewModel.setTextName( binding.editTextTextPersonName.text.toString() )` right?  Not working...

Comment: Are you using Navigation 2.4 (currently up to Navigation 2.4.0-rc01)? That's the only version that saves the state of each bottom nav.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, my dependencies section contains `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'`. 
Do I need to process somehow the state of fragments in the Activity class?

Comment: That's the version of Lifecycle (that's why what you pasted starts with `androidx.lifecycle`). You're looking for the `androidx.navigation` version.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Right, it was 2.3.5. I have changed it to `implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0-rc01'` and `implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0-rc01'`. And now it works!!!  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx` and `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx` dependencies version. They were `2.3.5`.

I have changed them as follows (thanks to @ianhanniballake)

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0-rc01' 
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0-rc01'
```

and the problem has gone